# C++ linker error after change in thrift file

Tags: c++, thrift

I think this is related to C++ linker error than to thrift. I made a change to the thrift file and regenerated cpp & java classes. After this change, I started getting linker errors in cpp. Here is the error

Undefined symbols:

`"com::XXXX::thrift::employee::SavingsInfo::operator<(com::XXXX::thrift::employee::SavingsInfo const&) const", referenced from:
      std::less::operator()(com::XXXX::thrift::employee::SavingsInfo const&, com::XXXX::thrift::employee::SavingsInfo const&) constin employee_types.o 

ld: symbol(s) not found 

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  

make: *** [ThriftCPPSamples] Error 1`

I added SavingsInfo type to thrift file, this is the change that I made. I give all the options mentioned in the doc to g++. I gave `-I/usr/local/include/thrift`,
`-I/path-to-boost`, `-L/path-to-boost-lib`, `-lthrift`. But after the change I started getting the above linker error. I couldn't understand the reason for this. The error points to something that was generated by thrift. What could be the reason for the error?

This error is about "operator <", so I am posting only the code relevant to it. Full code is available from the two links provided at the end.

**employee_types.h**

```
class SavingsInfo {
public:
    std::string name;
    double amount;
    bool operator == (const SavingsInfo & rhs) const { /*...*/ }
    bool operator != (const SavingsInfo &rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }
    bool operator < (const SavingsInfo & ) const;
    uint32_t read(::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* iprot);
    uint32_t write(::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot) const;
};

class EmployeeInfo {
public:
    int32_t id;
    std::string name;
    double salary;
    bool contract;
    std::set<std::string>  dependents;
    std::set<SavingsInfo>  savings;
    bool operator == (const EmployeeInfo & rhs) const { /*...*/ }
    bool operator != (const EmployeeInfo &rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }
    bool operator < (const EmployeeInfo & ) const;
    uint32_t read(::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* iprot);
    uint32_t write(::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot) const;
};
```

**employee_types.cpp**

```
uint32_t EmployeeInfo::read(::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* iprot) {
    uint32_t xfer = 0;
    std::string fname;
    ::apache::thrift::protocol::TType ftype;
    int16_t fid;
    xfer += iprot->readStructBegin(fname);
    using ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolException;
    while (true)
    {
        xfer += iprot->readFieldBegin(fname, ftype, fid);
        if (ftype == ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_STOP) {
            break;
        }
        switch (fid)
        {
            // removed the case statements which deal with reading other fields
        case 6:
            if (ftype == ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_SET) {
                {
                    this->savings.clear();
                    uint32_t _size6;
                    ::apache::thrift::protocol::TType _etype9;
                    iprot->readSetBegin(_etype9, _size6);
                    uint32_t _i10;
                    for (_i10 = 0; _i10 < _size6; ++_i10)
                    {
                        SavingsInfo _elem11;
                        xfer += _elem11.read(iprot);
                        this->savings.insert(_elem11);
                    }
                    iprot->readSetEnd();
                }
                this->__isset.savings = true;
            } else {
                xfer += iprot->skip(ftype);
            }
            break;
        default:
            xfer += iprot->skip(ftype);
            break;
        }
        xfer += iprot->readFieldEnd();
    }
    xfer += iprot->readStructEnd();
    return xfer;
}

uint32_t EmployeeInfo::write(::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot) const {
    uint32_t xfer = 0;
    // removed the write statements for other fields
    xfer += oprot->writeStructBegin("EmployeeInfo");
    xfer += oprot->writeFieldBegin("savings", ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_SET, 6);
    {
        xfer += oprot->writeSetBegin(::apache::thrift::protocol::T_STRUCT,   
            this->savings.size());
        std::set<SavingsInfo> ::const_iterator _iter13;
        for (_iter13 = this->savings.begin(); _iter13 != this->savings.end(); ++_iter13)
        {
            xfer += (*_iter13).write(oprot);
        }
        xfer += oprot->writeSetEnd();
    }
    xfer += oprot->writeFieldEnd();
    xfer += oprot->writeFieldStop();
    xfer += oprot->writeStructEnd();
    return xfer;
}
```

Couple of other things that I have tried:

1. Instead of set<SavingsInfo>, if I use SavingsInfo, it works fine.
2. Commented "operator <" in employee_types.h since I couldn't figure out where this was getting used. I got the following build error

`Building file: ../src/employee_types.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/thrift -I/Users/raghava/Software/Boost_C++_Library/boost_1_43_0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/employee_types.d" -MT"src/employee_types.d" -o"src/employee_types.o" "../src/employee_types.cpp"
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_function.h: In member function 'bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = com::xxxx::thrift::employee::SavingsInfo]':
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:982:   instantiated from 'std::pair::iterator, bool> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(const _Val&) [with _Key = com::xxxx::thrift::employee::SavingsInfo, _Val = com::xxxx::thrift::employee::SavingsInfo, _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity, _Compare = std::less, _Alloc = std::allocator]'
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_set.h:307:   instantiated from 'std::pair, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator, bool> std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const _Key&) [with _Key = com::xxxx::thrift::employee::SavingsInfo, _Compare = std::less, _Alloc = std::allocator]'
../src/employee_types.cpp:163:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_function.h:227: error: no match for 'operator<' in '__x < __y'
make: *** [src/employee_types.o] Error 1`

Complete source code of these 2 files is given in below links. The other link is in the comments (I cannot post it until I get 10 pts of reputation).

employee_types.cpp -- http://pastebin.com/7dLtstCK
employee_types.h -- http://pastebin.com/JGzE8V6J

Thank you.

Regards,
Raghava.

Comment: @Raghava: I have tried to somewhat format your post. I also added your second link (without any problems), you can delete your comment now. However, I would suggest you try to reduce this problem to the __smallest possible program__ which still exhibits it and __directly put that into your question__. Potentially helpful readers often won't follow external links and attempt to understand too much code. Usually, you find your problem while distilling the code to a minimal example, but if you don't, you'll have a perfect sample to put into your question.

Comment: @sbi: Thank u for formatting, it looks much better now. However, part of the error enclosed within <> seems to have disappeared. So I did a bit of formatting. A user cannot publish 2 links unless his/her reputation score is above 10, so had to put other link in comments. Sorry, but, I cannot figure out a subset of the code which would give the same error. It has only 2classes and they are auto-generated. I tried for a subset but ran into other linker errors.

Comment: @Raghava: I'm sorry for messing up with the formatting. I didn't look close enough. I've done you the favor to put the link back in. You can delete the comment again. But as you can see, my predictions were right: nobody bothered to look at two rather big, externally linked files. You need to understand that the people answering questions here do so in their spare time or while they wait for the compiler. They don't take/have much time to investigate and understand a problem. If you want answers, you need to make it as easy as possible.

Comment: As for your additional link problems: Just also comment out calls to the functions which throw additional linker errors. As long as the original error stays, that's exactly what you want.

Comment: providing link for reference - employee_types.h -- http://pastebin.com/JGzE8V6J

@sbi: I have removed parts of the code not relevant to this error. I hope this helps me :).

Comment: Well, I haven't ever worked with thrift, but I can say that operator < for employee isn't present in \*.cpp file, so the error is not suprising. \*.h has only forward declaration of operator < for employee class. It would be nice if you had maintained some kind of code repository (say, git repository) and could search for change that caused the bug (say, using *git bisect* or *git diff*). I would try to recover previous version of file and try to guess what caused the bug.

Comment: @SigTerm: Thank u for the reply :). Yes, I found it surprising too, that there is no definition. But it works if I don't use set<>. The complete code of these 2 files are in the links given (one in the post and another one in the comments). These files were generated by thrift.

Comment: @Raghava: Yep, @SigTerm is right. You have a declaration for `operator<()`, but no implementation. That's the problem. FYI: All associative containers, including `std::set`, need to compare their elements. To do that, they use `std::less<T>`, which, if it isn't specialized for a type, calls that type's `operator<`. (That's why the error goes away when you don't use `std::set`.)

Comment: BTW: That code is so horrible, I wouldn't even know where to start telling you what's wrong with it.

Comment: @sbi: Ok, so that means I have to implement operator <() method. They haven't mentioned this in their doc. Those files were generated by Thrift. So I cannot improve the code but I would like to know what is bad about it. That would help in my coding.

Comment: @sbi & SigTerm: Thank u for your answers. The linker error got resolved after adding the definition for operator<. I compiled the classes from Thrift src using the operator<() method they provide.