# Thrift C++ Linker Error (Boost smart pointers)

Tags: c++, thrift

I was following the simple Thrift tutorial in order to make a simple server for deployment(found here: https://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageC%2B%2B/).

However, despite copying the skeleton exactly and linking using the tutorial, I ran into the following linker error, even after properly linking with Thrift using `-lthrift` and `-L/usr/local/lib`:

```
gen-cpp/server.o: In function `main':
/home/will/Documents/Research_2018/Thrift-Javascript-to-CPP/server.cpp:56: 
undefined reference to `apache::thrift::server::TSimpleServer::TSimpleServer
(boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::TProcessor> const&, 
boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::transport::TServerTransport> const&, 
boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::transport::TTransportFactory> const&, 
boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolFactory> const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I had downloaded and compiled Thrift from the latest tarball (version 0.11.0). After comparing the symbol tables of the object file for my `server.o` file and the library file for Thrift in `/usr/local/lib`, it appeared as though the Thrift library compiled using `std::smart_pointer` instead of `boost::smart_pointer`, even after I added

```
AC_DEFINE([FORCE_BOOST_FUNCTIONAL], [], [Forces boost usage])
AC_DEFINE([FORCE_BOOST_SMART_PTR], [], [Forces boost usage of smart ptrs])
```

to the configure.ac file for the Thrift library. My compiler doesn't have built-in C++11 support, but it supports functionality with the `std=c++11` flag. How can I resolve this linker error?

(Examined the questions at [C++ linker error in Apache Thrift tutorial - undefined symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874016/c-linker-error-in-apache-thrift-tutorial-undefined-symbols) and [C++ linker error after change in thrift file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330789/c-linker-error-after-change-in-thrift-file) with no success).

Answer (score 0):

The root of this error was that compiling my Thrift library with C++11 support through the `std=c++11` flag caused some sort of confusion. The way I resolved this was by removing the:

```
AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11([noext], [optional])
```

macro from the configure.ac file. This meant the library no longer compiled with C++11 support, and it relied fully upon `boost::smart_pointer`.

Comment: I know that at one point, I had to rebuild my Boost libraries in order to add C++11 support. Perhaps your Boost libraries were not compiled with that support enabled.

Answer (score 0):

@Will Brackenbury

I delete AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11([noext], [optional]), but encounter below error

> undefined reference to
>   `apache::thrift::server::TThreadedServer::TThreadedServer(std::shared_ptr
>   const&, std::shared_ptr
>   const&, std::shared_ptr
>   const&, std::shared_ptr
>   const&, std::shared_ptr
>   const&)'

Comment: Unfortunately, based on that it looks like you aren't experiencing the same errors I did. Your library expects the `std::` version of the shared pointers. I would put the lines back in the file, and look back at other potential error sources.